# Java Painting a Triangle and Trying to use other Swing Objects

Tags: java, swing, awt, paint, graphics2d

I am having a bit of an issue using Netbeans to design a GUI (Yeah im lazy :\ ) and manually trying to paint a triangle onto the JFrame. The Swing Components are 'covered up' until I press tab and put focus on the objects. Ive attached a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzBOH.png) and code below of the issue.

All of the auto generated code for the GUI is in the initComponents() portion of the code. And the Triage generating is in the override code for the JFrame Paint method.
 What it looks like is happening is the initComponents code is run before the paint, since the object is created before setVisibile(true). Once setVisible(true) is called then the paint method paints over all of the generated objects initComponents created. Just looking for a solution so that nothing gets covered up.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 $/*
  * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
  * and open the template in the editor.
  */

 /*
  * SimpleClient.java
  *
  * Created on Sep 22, 2011, 11:38:30 AM
  */
 package Assignment3;

 import java.awt.Graphics;

 /**
  *
  * @author Mark
  */
 public class SimpleClient extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/** Creates new form SimpleClient */
public SimpleClient() {
    initComponents();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    int[] xPoints = {100, 100, 200};
    int[] yPoints = {100, 200, 200};
    g.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, 3);
}

/** This method is called from within the constructor to
 * initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
 * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
private void initComponents() {

    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(103, 103, 103)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(238, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(220, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(60, 60, 60))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SimpleClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SimpleClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SimpleClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SimpleClient.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            new SimpleClient().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some quick recommendations:

- Don't draw directly in the JFrame.
- Draw instead in a JComponent such as a JPanel.
- Override the paintComponent method of the JPanel, not the paint method.
- Call super.paintComponent(g), usually as the first method call of your paintComponent method to allow your JPanel to do its housekeeping and to erase old images.
- Read several tutorials on Swing graphics because for many of us (me especially), it's not intuitive and you'll have to break some assumptions to do it correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Don't override the paint() method of a Top Level Container (JFrame, JDialog...).

Custom painting is done by override the paintCompnent() method of a JPanel (or JComponent). Then you add the component to the content pane of the frame. Don't forget to also override the getPreferredSize() method of the component so the layout managers will work properly.

Read up on [Custom Painting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.